# Getting the jQuery object/reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Here I'm wrapping an HTML tag with another tag '$holder' below.

```
  $holder = $('<div />')
    .addClass('joverlaytext')
    .css({
        position:'relative', 
    });
  $(this).wrap($holder);
```

Now after this statment how to get the object/reference to this newly created HTML element, ie. jQuery obj of '$holder'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just continue the chain, e.g.:

```
$(this).wrap($holder).show();
```

If you look at the [manipulation methods documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation), .wrap(elem) returns a jQuery object, so chaining or

```
var result = $(this).wrap($holder);
```

will work.

Answer (score 0):

Just continue to use $holder as normal, placing it in a wrap function will not change it's jQuery object reference. So you could do this.

```
  $holder = $('<div />')
    .addClass('joverlaytext')
    .css({
        position:'relative', 
    });
  $(this).wrap($holder);
  $holder.show().doTheFunkyChickenDance();
```

Also as always, try not to use $(this), instead cache the object lookup by doing this

```
var $this = $(this);
// then just use $this as normal so
$this.wrap($holder);
```

Using the var keyword is also important, as it creates a locale variable rather than a global variable which should be avoided to stop banging heads on walls later down the track.